# Сумма значений ключей во вложенных объектах

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Не могу придумать как качественно решить следующую задачу:
есть объект, в него вложены еще объекты или массивы объектов. Нужно посчитать сумму всех значений определенного ключа. Не известно сколько уровней вложения.

Пример объекта (testObject):

```
{
   "title": "1",
   "amount": 4,
   "secondObject": {"title": "2", "price": 123, "amount": 8},
   "array": [
      0: {"title": "2", "amount": 2},
      1: {"title": "2", "amount": 3}
   ]
}
```

В этом примере мне нужно посчитать сумму всех значений ключа amount.

```
sumField(testObject, "amount"); // 17
```

Помогите придумать элегантное решение данной задачи. Без проблем пойму ES6 код, он даже в приоритете. Не против решения на любом другом языке или псевдокоде.

Comment: Для такой задачи нужно использовать рекурсию https://learn.javascript.ru/recursion

Comment: А некачественно можете?

Comment: @Igor Могу, а вы можете?

Comment: Рекурсия и есть быстрое и простое решение в вашем случае. Погуглите примеры перебора массивов эти способом.

Comment: @YuriPokhylko Для моей задачи нужно обходить относительно большые объекты. Что будет быстрее: рекурсия или же мой вариант с преобразованием объекта в строку (который я добавил в ответы)?

Comment: Как Вы думаете, нужно для сериализации пройти по всем вложенным объектам?

Comment: Определенно. Думаю вам известно что это можно реализовать многими способами.
Даже если это реализовано через рекурсию, вопрос был составлен так: что быстрее: реализация сериализации в JS, или инструменты, которыми я буду описывать алгоритм для обхода объекта

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответы, вот что у меня по итогу получилось. Если у кого есть варианты лучше, пожалуйста напишите.

```js
function sumField(obj, key) {
    let fieldIterator = JSON.stringify(obj).matchAll('(?<="' + key + '":)[0-9]*');
    let it = fieldIterator.next(), result = 0;
    while (!it.done) {
        result += it.value[0] - 0;
        it = fieldIterator.next();
    }
    return result;
}

let testObject = {
    "amount": 4,
    "title": "1",
    "object1": {"title": "2", "price": 123, "amount": 4},
    "object2": {"amount": 4, "title": "2", "price": 123},
    "array": [
        {"amount": 2, "title": "2"},
        {"title": "2", "amount": 3}
    ]
};

console.log(sumField(testObject, "amount"));
```

Comment: Не работает. Поставьте `amount` первым свойством.

Comment: Исправил, теперь все работает

Comment: Мне кажется, можно сделать вариант с рекурсией и прогнать через тесты два варианта. И потом уже сравнивать, что лучше. Более того, реализация сериализации в разных движках может работать по разному, поэтому какое семейство браузеров вас интересует?

Comment: Это плохое решение. Попробуйте `sumField(testObject, "[")`.

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов :

```js
function sumNestedObjectValues(obj) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] === "object") {
      sum += sumNestedObjectValues(obj[key]);
    } else if (typeof obj[key] === "number") {
      sum += obj[key];
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

let obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: 2,
    d: {
      e: 3
    }
  }
};

let summ = sumNestedObjectValues(obj);
console.log(summ); // Return 6
```